# Snap.js - how to set attribute to loaded svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have a created simple snapjs sample here https://plnkr.co/edit/CyeVHuuuWrTAy1yKsp4d?p=preview

This is my Script - I am loading an svg and I would like to paint it in green.
Surprisingly not the svg is colored, but the "bigCircle", which I draw as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = Snap("#svg");
  var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);
  Snap.load("world.svg", function (f) {
      var world = s.append(f);
      world.attr({
        fill: "#bada55",
      });
      bigCircle.drag();
      world.drag();
  });
})
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your world svg is not being coloured? https://plnkr.co/edit/mAw7mqzicIX3ugvBQyDa?p=preview

Comment: @Daniel Shillcock: No, it's just grey, which is the original color of the svg. Same with your Plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the world after you place it. You are trying to do this with:

```
var world = s.append(f)
```

But that doesn't return the paths that make up the world. It returns the entire svg. I would add the world first and then select it. I fixed it by adding this line:

```
world=s.select('[id="layer1"]')
```

I saw that the world is all grouped under that id in your svg. Once it's selected, you can apply color/drag like you wanted. Here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/t4JmZMz4JPJ0dDb95aQc?p=preview

Comment: thanks, that works. I wonder why the world map drags half speed, but that's not important for my project.